# I need to make boxplots with manually created percentiles

Tags: r, boxplot

I have simulated data and recorded only the relevant percentiles of these simulations.  When I make boxplots of them, I believe that the boxplot command is calculating certain default percentiles of the data vector that I input (I don't even know what the default percentiles are although I could guess) and plotting these as the boxplot hinges.  The reason for this is that the hinges do not appear to line up on the y-axis with the actual simulation percentiles I have recorded.

I instead need the boxplot command to understand that the data I give it are the percentiles to be shown as the hinges, and not to assume that this is raw data from which to calculate percentiles.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Comment: Sp draw a boxplot from the 5 summary values instead of first computing them? Look at the source code for `boxplot.default` in particular towards then end when `bxp` is called. It does exactly that.

Comment: When I do this, it identifies the min and max of the 5-entry vector that I input as outliers, rather than the min and max.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `bxp` which is what boxplot calls to create the graph.   Suppose that you have the fivenum summary `c(4, 5, 5.5, 6, 7)`. You must also specify "the number of points", the outliers and the upper and lower extremes of the notch. I will use no outliers.

```
bxp(list(stats = matrix(c(4, 5, 5.5, 6, 7), nrow=5),
    n = 100, conf = matrix(c(5,6), nrow=2), out  = numeric(),
    group = numeric(), names = ""))
```

[image: Boxplot from stats]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I have resolved the issue.